# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Windows Phone Crashes

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a hybrid application using IBM MobileFirst 7.1 and testing on a Windows Phone device.
We are making a lot of tests and we have some random crashes on application startup

First crash log:

```
The header x-wl-clientlog-deviceId has an empty value.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at IBM.Worklight.WLNativeXHRSender.responseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}
```

Second crash log:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()
   at IBM.Worklight.WLConfig.writeWLPref(String prefName, String prefValue)
   at IBM.Worklight.WLCookieManager.storeCookiesInIsolatedStorage()
   at IBM.Worklight.WLNativeXHRSender.responseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}
```

The device used for tests is a Nokia Lumia 1320 running on Windows Phone 8.1

The used IBM MobileFirst version is 7.1.0.00.20160513-1010

The used environment is Windows Phone (Silverlight)

These logs seems to be related to Worklight / MobileFirst native code. Can you confirm that ? Are there any fixes for that ?

Please advice

Comment: It will be more beneficial if you could provide a reproduction of your crash. Just the log is not enough.

Comment: The crash is happening randomly, and I can run the application dozens of times without getting any crash.

Comment: Are you using the Windows Phone (Silverlight) environment or the Windows  Universal environment ?

Comment: When does the crashes occur? What are the steps leading upto the crashes

Comment: We are using the Windows Phone (Silverlight) environment, and the crashes occur on application launch

Comment: @WiPhone, I think it'd be simpler if you'll provide us with a MobileFirst project where this crash occurs. There's nothing to work with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question required opening an IBM support ticket, and is thus handled as PMR #74734,024,677. The IBM development team is investigating it using a sample application provided by the customer.

Comment: thanks
How can we follow the status of this PMR ? Will you update this response once the PMR closed ?

Comment: Aren't you the customer who opened the PMR? You can open another PMR, mentioning the PMR number I've mentined above.